# question finding limit

Tags: limits

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left[\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x$$

Comment: What is $a$? Any real number? Also, what have you tried? You should edit your question and include this among other things.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout: the resolution shows that $a$ can be any real.

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1-\frac ax+o\left(\frac1x\right)+\frac1x+o\left(\frac1x\right)=1+\frac{1-a}x+o\left(\frac1x\right)$$

so that by the well-known definition of the natural exponential, the requested limit is

$$e^{1-a}.$$

The works with any value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider first
$$A=\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a\implies \log(A)=-a \log \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ So, using Taylor series
$$\log(A)=-a\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=1-\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a (a+1)}{2 x^2}-\frac{a (a+1) (a+2)}{6
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$A+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=1+\frac{1-a}{x}+\frac{a (a+1)}{2 x^2}-\frac{ a (a+1)
   (a+2)-1}{6x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$x \log\left[\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]=(1-a)+\frac{3 a-1}{2 x}+\frac{3 a^2-11a+1}{6
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$\left[\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^a+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right]^x=e^{1-a}\left(1+\frac{3 a-1}{2 x}+\frac{39 a^2-62a+7}{24 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)$$